# MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, installation

I'm trying to install and run MySQL 8.0.22 on Mac (Mojave) and have been unable to do so.

I am trying to use the command

`$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p`

and am prompted to enter the root password, which I do but am then met with the error:

`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I am 100% sure that I am entering the correct password I created during installation (and I have reinstalled multiple times now), so I don't understand what the problem is.

I have looked at other posts online about how to fix this, but none work.

Does anyone have any insight into this problem with a fresh install? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check.

- Check any .my.cnf files are present in the current directory which overrides the password.
- Login with the command `mysql -uroot -p -h<<ipaddress>>`